# Regular Expression for removing numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

can anyone please tell me how to remove the last numbers before the space using Regular Expression in javascript

```
ABCD 154 => ABCD  
ACR 15 => ACR   
SA 12S 8945 => SA 12S
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the end of string `$` anchor to replace the preceding space and numbers that follow at the end of the string.

```
str = str.replace(/ [0-9]+$/, '');
```

If you want to retain the space character, just remove it from the regular expression.

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/172874)

Comment: what's the difference with this to Yury's answer, which is better

Comment: My answer matches a space character, his matches various whitespace characters, `[0-9]` matches only `0123456789` characters, while `\d` matches `[0-9]` and other digit characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
'SA 12S 8945'.replace(/\s\d+$/, '')
```